# Incorrect groups total on Solr 3.6.1 Distributed Search when groups.ngroups=true

Tags: solr, grouping, distributed

I have a number of solr cores set up [Solr 3.5 & Jetty 7.4.5], with identical schemas, and unique keys across each core. When doing a distributed search [e.g. 2 Shards] using "groups.ngroups=true" the total groups value returned each time is the sum of the group values for each shard, rather than the sum total of results after grouping [e.g. (unique values of Shard A) + (unique values of Shard B), rather than Unique values of (Shard A and Shard B combined)].

My hope was that this problem was addressed by SOLR-3436 [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3436], and was thus corrected in Solr 3.6.1, but when I updated my Solr version to 3.6.1, the incorrect group totals remained.  My question is whether this behavior [Total groups value is the sum of each distinct shards group total] is the expected behavior in Solr 3.6.1, or if I have some sort of error in my Solr installation, and I'm not seeing the corrected version from SOLR-3436.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
--Ron Veenstra

Comment: Can you make sure that the patch changes provided in the Jira exists in the jars you have ??

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported in Solr.

To get the expected behavior, you need to ensure that all documents with the same value for the field used for grouping are on the same shard. [SOLR-2592](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2592) addresses this but you will have to wait for Solr 4.1 release to take advantage of it.